# apidoc cli command doesn't work

Tags: javascript, api-doc

I have tried cli apidoc command **apidoc -i C:/Users/Lenovo -o C:/Users/Lenovo/apidoc**, but all of them resolve into same error:

> ```
> error: No files found. 
> { Path: './' }
> ```

Please help.